# How to allow creation and deletion of a database or collections with user and password

Tags: mongodb, users

I created a user with the role of **userAdminAnyDatabase**

```
db.createUser({user: "Username", pwd: "password", roles: [{role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin"}]})
```

and also user with the role of **userAdmin** for a single db in the mongo shell.

```
db.createUser({user: "Username", pwd: "password", roles: [{role: "userAdmin", db: "myDB"}]})
```

But when I create or delete collections in **myDB** it's not asking me for the user name or password. What is the point of creating a user then?

I want the creation and deletion of databases and collections only when I give in the admin credentials.

Answer (score 0):

No, system don't work that way. You must enable [authentication and authorization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/) of your mongodb.

After that, you log in with userAdmin credentials and you (only) have authorization to do userAdmin work, not system admin work. But remember to create super-admin user (before enabling authenticaton) or you end up to situation that you don't have superuser (root) who can give other needed rights.

Comment: Yes after hours of research I got it now. The mongodb documentation haven't mentioned the superuser which is what the problem was. They should have mentioned to add a user with the `role : root` first and given better examples